# Custom Fields Not in Search Results

Tags: custom-field, search

I noticed that the content of my custom fields is not in my search results.  Is there a good remedy for this?

I could just hardcode my content into page templates but I would like the content to be searchable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an custom plugin for your custom fields

```
function fb_custom_search_where($where) {
    // put the custom fields into an array
    $customs = array('custom_field1', 'custom_field2', 'custom_field3');

    foreach( $customs as $custom ) {
    $query .= " OR (";
    $query .= "( m.meta_key = '$custom' )";
    $query .= " AND ( m.meta_value  LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}' )";
        $query .= ")";
    }

    $where = " AND ({$query}) AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish') ";
    return($where);
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'fb_custom_search_where' );
```

Also you can check the plugin [WP Custom Fields Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/) and you have adhoc an solution.

Comment: very strange code... $term is empty variable so there will be no results. Also i can bet the $wpdb should be global. strange that this answer was chosen, cause it's not working.

Comment: i think this example was understand from the people, there have ask the question, its only an example.

Comment: This code does not work at all, beware!

Comment: Why, it works on different installs. But it is important, that you change the identifier of the custom fields in the first array.

Comment: It doesn't work, becuase it is assumed that the people using it have, at least, minimal programming knowledge. Should you modify it correctly, it will modify the SQL query appropriately.