# Query posts by custom fields

Tags: wp-query, search

I am making a theme for a hotel, and I need to be able to provide functionality to search by the following custom fields: Location and Price. I need to be able to query them from the query string itself... ie:

yoursite.com/?post_type=rooms&location=south

yoursite.com/?post_type=rooms&price=20.95

yoursite.com/?post_type=rooms&location=north&price=35

I have found many different questions/answers to this, but none of them seem to specifically address my issue.

This one, notably, I believe is really close to solving the issue for me:
[Query posts and filter at query time by value of custom meta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43799/query-posts-and-filter-at-query-time-by-value-of-custom-meta)

It doesn't make much sense to me. I am used to PHP, however I am new to WordPress as a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out (finally) after about 12 hours of screwing around.

The answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40072/custom-fields-not-in-search-results?rq=1#answer-40100) gave me 98% of the answer, and the rest was simply using the appropriate hooks to modify it for my use and to include the postmeta table.